# How do I stop MPMoviePlayerController from showing my app's icon on the iPod controls in iOS4.0+?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller, multitasking

I use an `MPMoviePlayerController` to play a movie inside my application.

When the movie is playing, if I double-press the home button and scroll to the left (where the iPod icon usually is as well as the "lock orientation" button), I see my app's icon.

The play controls control the movie inside my app, even if I had navigated to a different view controller inside my application.

I'd like to turn this "feature" off.  Any ideas?

As a side note I am controlling the audio session manually, and the session is `AVAudioSessionPlayback` at that point.

I've poked around the MPMoviePlayerController class reference for awhile to see if I could find anything, but it seems to make no reference of this behavior.

When I put my app into the background, it does what you would expect - returns the iPod icon to the bar.

Comment: I don't know if this can be disabled or not, but I'd question needing to.  It also represents being able to stop from the earphone pause/volume/mic dongle or other external devices.

Comment: Peter, I think you may be right.  I'll leave the question open for now in case anyone can definitively give an answer, but it's probably tied to the remote as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know why you would want that, setting your Audio Session to `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient` should disable that feature (but also disables the ability to play in the background).

Also make sure that `useApplicationAudioSession` on your `MPMoviePlayerController` is set to `YES`.